# Class member of Interface and base class

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a base class called `Graph` and an interface called `IDataTip`.

I've got a number of classes that implement both of these, for example:

```
class TreeGraph : Graph, IDataTip
{
  //interface implementation
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to declare a member of *another* class such that the type of the member requires classes that match *both* the abstract class and the interface?

For example, in the following class:

```
class GraphExporter
{
    public Object GraphWithDataTip {set; get;}
}
```

I would like to be able to replace the `Object` type with something that indicates that `GraphWithDataTip` should be inherit from `Graph` and implement `IDataTip`. Is there any way to do this? Or if not, could somebody recommend a more sensible design?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try clarify your question? maybe with an example?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, clarified with an example just now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as though you want either:

- a new base type (`abstract class thing : Graph, IDataTip`) to be used for your parameter
- a generic method of the form `void MyMethod<T>(T thing) where T : Graph, IDataTip`

Alternatively, you could cast the parameter within your method and throw an exception if it's not suitable, but this would be a runtime-only check.

Comment: Seems like a new base type is the best way to go. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 6):

You could use *generic constraints*:

```
public class FooClass<T> where T: Graph, IDataTip
{
    public T Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't really have a need for the class to be generic (should've been more specific in the original question, sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface that both Graph and IDataTip implement, and then have your member of *another* class be an instance of that new interface.

```
//new interface
interface IGraphAndDataTip
{
}

class Graph : IGraphAndDataTip
{
}

interface IDataTip : IGraphAndDataTip
{
}

class AnotherClass
{
    //implements both graph and IDataTip
    IGraphAndDataTip MyMember;
}
```

Comment: No, your code is exactly the wrong way around.  `MyMember` can be a class that implements neither of `Graph` and `IDataTip` in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean a derived class of your base class? Is this what you mean?

```
public abstract class Graph {
    public abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public interface IDataTip {
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class MyClassDerivedFromGraph: Graph, IDataTip {
    void SomeMethod() {
       // This method matches both the interface method and the base class method.
    }
}
```